# Primefaces poll updates whole form instead of the desired component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dashboard in my form which includes three panels and each of them needs to get updated with different intervals:

- interval for panel1: 65 seconds
- interval for panel2: 30 seconds
- interval for panel3: 45 seconds

For this purpose I'm trying to use Primefaces poll component:

**myPage.xhtml:** (Primefaces version: 5.2)

```
<h:form id="myForm">

    <p:poll interval="65" update=":panel1" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel1}"/>

    <p:poll interval="30" update=":panel2" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel2}" />

    <p:poll interval="45" update=":panel3" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel3}" />

    <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{bean.dashboardModel}">
        <p:panel id="panel1" header="Panel 1">
            <p:chart id="myPieChart" type="pie" model="#{myBean.myPieChartModel}" />
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel id="panel2" header="Panel 2">
            <p:chart id="myLineChart" type="line"
                model="#{myBean.myLineChartModel1}" />
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel id="panel3" header="panel3">
            <p:chart id="myLineChart2" type="line"
                model="#{myBean.myLineChartModel2}" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:dashboard>
</h:form>
```

However all the polls I'm using are not just updating the panels which they're associated with, instead they're updating the whole form. How can I fix this?

Any suggestions appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine but you must change update reference

```
<p:poll interval="65" update="panel1" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel1}"/>

<p:poll interval="30" update="panel2" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel2}" />

<p:poll interval="45" update="panel3" listener="#{myBean.updatePanel3}" />
```

if you put :panel1 It refers to the root no from 'myForm'

Answer (score -1):

You could test putting prependId=false into the form and update="board:panel1" in your polls. Have you checked if the polls are calling your get method for model component in chart?

Comment: `prependId="false"` should never ever be used.

Comment: @Kukeltje I wouldn't say "never", but indeed it should be avoided. The intention of this idea is to verify if he is calling the <p:panel> component accordingly in the <p:poll> update.

Comment: In ajax calls the prepended id  is should always be added in the update/render attribute, so it does not make a difference then, so yes, I'd say never ;-)